# Why are these migrated user profiles being left in a subfolder?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, sccm, system-center, usmt

When performing a user state migration from a Windows XP computer to a Windows 7 computer, destination profiles are not properly restored. As far as I can tell from log files the operation was "successful". The folder `C:\Users\Alice` gets created, for example, but is left as a stock profile that has never been logged on to. I can find all Alice's files under `C:\Users\Alice\Documents\Users\Alice`. In fact, moving all these files up three levels, refreshing permissions, and having 'Alice' log in  seems to work. The same thing happens to any user profiles on the source computer.

Our office is upgrading from Windows XP to Windows 7. We are using SCCM's "Operating System Deployment" feature to do that, which provides a more convenient interface to WDS and USMT. Our workflow for upgrading a user is the following:

1. Prepare a new Windows 7 computer with all software preinstalled.
2. run scanstate on current computer. I've tried this with users logged on, not logged on, and directly after a system reboot. The command we use is this: `C:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\OLY00030\x86\scanstate.exe \\our.domain.com\SMPSTOREf_0A6193F4$\9FFA0E271B4C910B242CA957BD42C8804EFF457D04FD1065B37593EFDCCAB806 /o /localonly /encrypt /key:**** /c /efs:copyraw /v:5 /l:C:\WINDOWS\system32\CCM\Logs\SMSTSLog\scanstate.log /progress:C:\WINDOWS\system32\CCM\Logs\SMSTSLog\scanstateprogress.log /i:C:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\OLY00030\x86\MigUser.XML /i:C:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\OLY00030\x86\MigApp.XML /vsc`
3. Run loadstate on the destination computer with the following command: `C:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\OLY0004E\amd64\loadstate.exe \\our.domain.com\SMPSTOREf_0A6193F4$\BBB172E1617AA419B2EAF13DC5F8A3B44D90F79F17EDC405E780140083730C1E /decrypt /key:**** /c /all /l:C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CCM\Logs\SMSTSLog\loadstate.log /progress:C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CCM\Logs\SMSTSLog\loadstateprogress.log /i:C:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\OLY0004E\amd64\miguser.xml /i:C:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\OLY0004E\amd64\migapp.xml`

Everything appears to run successfully. What follows is a trimmed-down version of `scanstateprogress.log` and `loadstateprogress.log`. Does anyone have insights into what may be causing this?

### scanstateprogress.log

```
07 Apr 2011, 15:37:57 -07:00, 00:00:00, program, scanstate.exe, productVersion, "6.1.7601.21645 (win7sp1_ldr.110119-1504)", computerName, IS018816, commandLine, "C:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\OLY00030\x86\scanstate.exe \\ops02.energy.wsu.edu\SMPSTOREf_0A6193F4$\9FFA0E271B4C910B242CA957BD42C8804EFF457D04FD1065B37593EFDCCAB806 /o /localonly /encrypt /key:**** /c /efs:copyraw /v:5 /l:C:\WINDOWS\system32\CCM\Logs\SMSTSLog\scanstate.log /progress:C:\WINDOWS\system32\CCM\Logs\SMSTSLog\scanstateprogress.log /i:C:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\OLY00030\x86\MigUser.XML /i:C:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\OLY00030\x86\MigApp.XML /vsc"
07 Apr 2011, 15:37:58 -07:00, 00:00:00, PHASE, Initializing
07 Apr 2011, 15:37:58 -07:00, 00:00:00, PHASE, Scanning
07 Apr 2011, 15:37:58 -07:00, 00:00:00, processingUser, AD\BILL
07 Apr 2011, 15:37:59 -07:00, 00:00:01, processingUser, AD\ALICE
07 Apr 2011, 15:37:59 -07:00, 00:00:02, processingUser, AD\DAVE
07 Apr 2011, 15:38:00 -07:00, 00:00:03, processingUser, IS018816\CANDACE
07 Apr 2011, 15:38:01 -07:00, 00:00:03, processingUser, AD\ERIN
07 Apr 2011, 15:38:02 -07:00, 00:00:04, processingUser, SYSTEM
07 Apr 2011, 15:38:02 -07:00, 00:00:05, PHASE, Estimating
07 Apr 2011, 15:38:03 -07:00, 00:00:05, estimatePercentageCompleted, 32
...
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:17 -07:00, 00:01:19, estimatePercentageCompleted, 97
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:23 -07:00, 00:01:25, estimatePercentageCompleted, 1
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:23 -07:00, 00:01:25, detectedUser, AD\BILL, includedInMigration, Yes
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:23 -07:00, 00:01:26, detectedUser, AD\ALICE, includedInMigration, Yes
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:23 -07:00, 00:01:26, detectedUser, AD\DAVE, includedInMigration, Yes
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:23 -07:00, 00:01:26, detectedUser, IS018816\HelpAssistant, includedInMigration, No
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:23 -07:00, 00:01:26, detectedUser, IS018816\Guest, includedInMigration, No
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:23 -07:00, 00:01:26, detectedUser, IS018816\ASPNET, includedInMigration, No
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:23 -07:00, 00:01:26, detectedUser, IS018816\CANDACE, includedInMigration, Yes
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:23 -07:00, 00:01:26, detectedUser, IS018816\SUPPORT_388945a0, includedInMigration, No
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:24 -07:00, 00:01:26, detectedUser, AD\ERIN, includedInMigration, Yes
....
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:24 -07:00, 00:01:26, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Start Menu", includedInMigration, Yes
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:24 -07:00, 00:01:26, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "My Documents", includedInMigration, Yes
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:24 -07:00, 00:01:26, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft Office 2007\Microsoft Office Word 2007", includedInMigration, Yes
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:24 -07:00, 00:01:26, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft Office 2007\Microsoft Office Excel 2007", includedInMigration, Yes
...
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:24 -07:00, 00:01:26, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft Office 2007\Microsoft Office Access 2007", includedInMigration, Yes
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:24 -07:00, 00:01:26, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft Office 2007\Microsoft Office SmartTags\Microsoft Lists SmartTags", includedInMigration, Yes
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:24 -07:00, 00:01:26, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft Office 2007\Microsoft Office SmartTags\Microsoft Place SmartTags", includedInMigration, Yes
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:24 -07:00, 00:01:26, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Desktop", includedInMigration, Yes
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:24 -07:00, 00:01:26, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Quick Launch", includedInMigration, Yes
....
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:26 -07:00, 00:01:28, totalSizeInMBToTransfer, 39493.47
07 Apr 2011, 15:39:26 -07:00, 00:01:28, PHASE, Collecting
...
07 Apr 2011, 16:01:47 -07:00, 00:23:49, totalPercentageCompleted, 28
07 Apr 2011, 16:01:51 -07:00, 00:23:54, totalPercentageCompleted, 29
07 Apr 2011, 16:01:54 -07:00, 00:23:56, error, UnableToOpen, objectName, "C:\WINDOWS\system32\CatRoot2 [edb.log]", action, Abort, errorText, "Read error 32 for C:\WINDOWS\system32\CatRoot2 [edb.log]. Windows error 32 description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
07 Apr 2011, 16:01:54 -07:00, 00:23:57, error, UnableToOpen, objectName, "C:\WINDOWS\system32\CatRoot2 [tmp.edb]", action, Abort, errorText, "Read error 32 for C:\WINDOWS\system32\CatRoot2 [tmp.edb]. Windows error 32 description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
07 Apr 2011, 16:02:54 -07:00, 00:24:57, totalPercentageCompleted, 30
07 Apr 2011, 16:02:58 -07:00, 00:25:00, error, UnableToOpen, objectName, "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [default]", action, Abort, errorText, "Read error 32 for C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [default]. Windows error 32 description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
07 Apr 2011, 16:02:58 -07:00, 00:25:00, error, UnableToOpen, objectName, "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [default.LOG]", action, Abort, errorText, "Read error 32 for C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [default.LOG]. Windows error 32 description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
07 Apr 2011, 16:02:58 -07:00, 00:25:01, error, UnableToOpen, objectName, "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [SAM]", action, Abort, errorText, "Read error 32 for C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [SAM]. Windows error 32 description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
07 Apr 2011, 16:02:58 -07:00, 00:25:01, totalPercentageCompleted, 30
07 Apr 2011, 16:02:58 -07:00, 00:25:01, error, UnableToOpen, objectName, "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [SAM.LOG]", action, Abort, errorText, "Read error 32 for C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [SAM.LOG]. Windows error 32 description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
07 Apr 2011, 16:02:59 -07:00, 00:25:01, error, UnableToOpen, objectName, "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [SECURITY]", action, Abort, errorText, "Read error 32 for C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [SECURITY]. Windows error 32 description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
07 Apr 2011, 16:02:59 -07:00, 00:25:01, error, UnableToOpen, objectName, "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [SECURITY.LOG]", action, Abort, errorText, "Read error 32 for C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [SECURITY.LOG]. Windows error 32 description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
07 Apr 2011, 16:02:59 -07:00, 00:25:01, error, UnableToOpen, objectName, "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [software]", action, Abort, errorText, "Read error 32 for C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [software]. Windows error 32 description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
07 Apr 2011, 16:03:00 -07:00, 00:25:02, error, UnableToOpen, objectName, "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [software.LOG]", action, Abort, errorText, "Read error 32 for C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [software.LOG]. Windows error 32 description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
07 Apr 2011, 16:03:01 -07:00, 00:25:03, error, UnableToOpen, objectName, "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [system]", action, Abort, errorText, "Read error 32 for C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [system]. Windows error 32 description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
07 Apr 2011, 16:03:01 -07:00, 00:25:04, error, UnableToOpen, objectName, "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [system.LOG]", action, Abort, errorText, "Read error 32 for C:\WINDOWS\system32\config [system.LOG]. Windows error 32 description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
07 Apr 2011, 16:03:23 -07:00, 00:25:26, totalPercentageCompleted, 30
07 Apr 2011, 16:03:27 -07:00, 00:25:30, totalPercentageCompleted, 31
...
07 Apr 2011, 16:04:28 -07:00, 00:26:30, processingUser, AD\ALICE
07 Apr 2011, 16:04:53 -07:00, 00:26:55, totalPercentageCompleted, 37
07 Apr 2011, 16:04:57 -07:00, 00:26:59, totalPercentageCompleted, 38
...
07 Apr 2011, 16:08:03 -07:00, 00:30:05, processingUser, SYSTEM
07 Apr 2011, 16:08:03 -07:00, 00:30:06, totalPercentageCompleted, 94
07 Apr 2011, 16:08:09 -07:00, 00:30:12, totalPercentageCompleted, 95
07 Apr 2011, 16:08:10 -07:00, 00:30:12, PHASE, Saving
07 Apr 2011, 16:08:18 -07:00, 00:30:20, totalPercentageCompleted, 100
07 Apr 2011, 16:08:18 -07:00, 00:30:20, errorCode, 0, numberOfIgnoredErrors, 0, message, "Successful run"
```

### loadstateprogress.log

```
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:16 -07:00, 00:00:00, program, loadstate.exe, productVersion, "6.1.7601.21645 (win7sp1_ldr.110119-1504)", computerName, IS020227, commandLine, "C:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\OLY0004E\amd64\loadstate.exe \\ops02.energy.wsu.edu\SMPSTOREf_0A6193F4$\BBB172E1617AA419B2EAF13DC5F8A3B44D90F79F17EDC405E780140083730C1E /decrypt /key:**** /c /all /l:C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CCM\Logs\SMSTSLog\loadstate.log /progress:C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CCM\Logs\SMSTSLog\loadstateprogress.log /i:C:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\OLY0004E\amd64\miguser.xml /i:C:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\OLY0004E\amd64\migapp.xml"
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:16 -07:00, 00:00:00, PHASE, Initializing
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:25 -07:00, 00:00:08, PHASE, Scanning
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:25 -07:00, 00:00:08, processingUser, IS020227\CANDACE
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:44 -07:00, 00:00:27, processingUser, AD\BILL
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:45 -07:00, 00:00:28, processingUser, AD\DAVE
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:45 -07:00, 00:00:28, processingUser, AD\ALICE
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:46 -07:00, 00:00:29, processingUser, AD\ERIN
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:46 -07:00, 00:00:29, processingUser, SYSTEM
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:47 -07:00, 00:00:30, PHASE, Estimating
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:47 -07:00, 00:00:30, estimatePercentageCompleted, 32
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:51 -07:00, 00:00:34, estimatePercentageCompleted, 97
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:53 -07:00, 00:00:37, detectedUser, IS020227\Administrator, includedInMigration, No
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:53 -07:00, 00:00:37, detectedUser, IS020227\CANDACE, includedInMigration, No
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:53 -07:00, 00:00:37, detectedUser, AD\BILL, includedInMigration, No
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:53 -07:00, 00:00:37, detectedUser, AD\DAVE, includedInMigration, No
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:53 -07:00, 00:00:37, detectedUser, AD\ALICE, includedInMigration, No
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:53 -07:00, 00:00:37, detectedUser, AD\ERIN, includedInMigration, No
08 Apr 2011, 15:49:53 -07:00, 00:00:37, detectedUser, IS020227\Guest, includedInMigration, No
...
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:00 -07:00, 00:00:43, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "WindowsSearchEngine", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:00 -07:00, 00:00:43, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft-Windows-themecpl", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:00 -07:00, 00:00:43, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Tablet PC Settings\Accessories\Microsoft-Windows-TabletPC-Journal", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:00 -07:00, 00:00:43, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Tablet PC Settings\Input Panel\Microsoft-Windows-TabletPC-InputPanel", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:00 -07:00, 00:00:43, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Tablet PC Settings\General Options\Microsoft-Windows-TabletPC-UIHub", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:00 -07:00, 00:00:43, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Tablet PC Settings\General Options\Microsoft-Windows-TabletPC-Platform-Input-Core", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:00 -07:00, 00:00:43, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Tablet PC Settings\Handwriting Recognition\Microsoft-Windows-TabletPC-InputPersonalization", includedInMigration, Yes
...
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Network and Internet\Networking Connections\Microsoft-Windows-PeerToPeerCollab", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Network and Internet\Networking Connections\Microsoft-Windows-Native-80211", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Network and Internet\Networking Connections\Microsoft-Windows-MPR", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Network and Internet\Networking Connections\Microsoft-Windows-Dot3svc", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft-Windows-DisplayConfigSettings", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft-Windows-DiagCpl", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Date, Time, Language and Region\Regional Language Options\Microsoft-Windows-TableDrivenTextService-Migration", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Date, Time, Language and Region\Regional Language Options\Microsoft-Windows-TextServicesFramework-Migration", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Date, Time, Language and Region\Regional Language Options\Microsoft-Windows-MUI-Settings", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Date, Time, Language and Region\Regional Language Options\Microsoft-Windows-International-Core", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Date, Time, Language and Region\Regional Language Options\Microsoft-Windows-IME-Traditional-Chinese-Core", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Date, Time, Language and Region\Regional Language Options\Microsoft-Windows-IME-Simplified-Chinese-Core", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Date, Time, Language and Region\Regional Language Options\Microsoft-Windows-Desktop_Technologies-Text_Input_Services-IME-Japanese-Core", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft-Windows-DesktopWindowManager-Core", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Security\Microsoft-Windows-Rights-Management-Client-v1-API", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Security\Security Options\Microsoft-Windows-Security-Vault", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Security\Security Options\Microsoft-Windows-Credential-Manager", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Appearance and Display\Windows Games Settings\Microsoft-Windows-GameExplorer", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Appearance and Display\Taskbar and Start Menu\Microsoft-Windows-stobject", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Appearance and Display\Taskbar and Start Menu\Microsoft-Windows-explorer", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Appearance and Display\Personalized Settings\Microsoft-Windows-uxtheme", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Appearance and Display\Personalized Settings\Microsoft-Windows-themeui", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Appearance and Display\Personalized Settings\Microsoft-Windows-shmig", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Appearance and Display\Personalized Settings\Microsoft-Windows-shell32", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Appearance and Display\Personalized Settings\Microsoft-Windows-CommandPrompt", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Help Settings\Microsoft-Windows-Help-Client", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-Win32k-Settings", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-Web-Services-for-Management-Core", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-UPnPSSDP", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:44, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-UPnPDeviceHost", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-UPnPControlPoint", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-Drivers", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-SQMApi", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-SQM-Consolidator-Base", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-RPC-Remote", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-RPC-Local", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-RPC-HTTP", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-Rasppp", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-RasMprDdm", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-RasBase", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-Microsoft-Data-Access-Components-(MDAC)-ODBC-DriverManager-Dll", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-ICM-Profiles", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-feclient", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:01 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-dpapi-keys", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-Crypto-keys", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-COM-DTC-Setup", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-COM-ComPlus-Setup", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-COM-Base", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Additional Options\Windows Core Settings\Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2-certs", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft-Windows-Client-SQM-Consolidator", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft-Windows-Audio-VolumeControl", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Accessibility\Accessibility Settings\Microsoft-Windows-accessibilitycpl", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Program-Data", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Application-Telemetry-Agent", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Program-Compatibility-Assistant", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Start Menu", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Favorites", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "My Pictures", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "My Documents", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "My Music", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "My Video", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Desktop", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Quick Launch", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft Office 2010\Microsoft Office Access 2010", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft Office 2010\Microsoft Office Excel 2010", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft Office 2010\Microsoft Office Outlook 2010", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft Office 2010\Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2010", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft Office 2010\Office 2010 Common Settings", includedInMigration, Yes
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:02 -07:00, 00:00:45, forUser, AD\ALICE, detectedComponent, "Microsoft Office 2010\Microsoft Office Word 2010 (32-bit)", includedInMigration, Yes
...
...
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:06 -07:00, 00:00:49, totalSizeInMBToTransfer, 32407.88
08 Apr 2011, 15:50:06 -07:00, 00:00:49, PHASE, Applying
...
08 Apr 2011, 15:59:37 -07:00, 00:10:20, processingUser, AD\ALICE
08 Apr 2011, 15:59:41 -07:00, 00:10:24, totalPercentageCompleted, 31
08 Apr 2011, 15:59:45 -07:00, 00:10:28, totalPercentageCompleted, 32
08 Apr 2011, 16:00:19 -07:00, 00:11:02, totalPercentageCompleted, 33
...
08 Apr 2011, 16:07:43 -07:00, 00:18:26, totalPercentageCompleted, 62
08 Apr 2011, 16:08:04 -07:00, 00:18:47, totalPercentageCompleted, 63
...
08 Apr 2011, 16:16:43 -07:00, 00:27:26, processingUser, SYSTEM
08 Apr 2011, 16:16:43 -07:00, 00:27:26, totalPercentageCompleted, 94
08 Apr 2011, 16:18:32 -07:00, 00:29:15, totalPercentageCompleted, 100
08 Apr 2011, 16:18:32 -07:00, 00:29:15, errorCode, 0, numberOfIgnoredErrors, 0, message, "Successful run"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out why both the User State Migration Tool and the Easy Transfer Utility that comes with  Windows 7 was failing to migrate user profiles.

In our network we map the My Documents, My Music, etc. special folders to a network location. Any user with such a mapping will have this problem. Our solution is to temporarily disable the remapping for each user as they are getting a new computer. Since there's no way to fully automate this (the user has to know that 'My Documents' doesn't point to their files) we're just going to use the Easy Transfer Utility.

### Updated: May 17, 2011

I found a [Microsoft blog article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/03/11/usmt-and-sf.aspx) confirming that using the USMT when folder redirection is in place does cause problems. Temporarily disabling folder redirection before running the tool gets us past this hurdle... and on to the next one.

The Windows Easy Transfer utility that comes with Windows seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be vague, but it sounds like there's something specified in your SCCM package that's directing the loadstate to place the files in a duplicate default user directory.  If you have a custom miguser.xml or a customized USMT task sequence in SCCM, look for the duplicated directory there.  Unfortunately I don't have enough information to answer your question precisely (would need all your xml files, package info).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I reviewed the USMT software package, capture/restore task sequences, and computer associatons; and may have found the problem. Before upgrading the new computer to Windows 7 I had set up a computer association between the two in SCCM's Operating System Deployment. Reinstalling an operating creates a new SCCM computer object (with the same name), but my association was still referencing the old one.

This may be what the problem is.

Comment: No, the broken association was not the problem. In another attempt I made some profiles transferred while others were not.

Comment: I was able to figure out what the issue was. Having users' special folders remapped to network locations is causing this problem. See my answer for more details.